# Why td does not work beside input type in javascript string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My javascript code like this :

```
var count = $('table.zui-table th.count').length;
var res = `<input type="hidden" name="test-`+(count+1)+`"><th><a>Test</a></th>`; 
$('#view-'+(count)).after(res);
```

Demo and full code like this : https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/dB93J/291/

If the code run, td on label `Test` not working. You can see it

If I remove `<input type="hidden" name="test-`+(count+1)+`"`, it works

But why it not working if use input type?

How can I solve it?

Comment: A `<tr>` can only have `<td>`s or `<th>`s as children. Anything else is semantically incorrect and won’t work.

Comment: @Xufox, In html, it works. You can see my html code

Comment: @Xufox, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139669/using-input-tags-directly-inside-table

Comment: And where in this Q&A do you see a `<td></td><input />` syntax? And no, it does not work. Look at the generated markup. The `<th>` node is missing, even though you wrote `<th><a>Test</a></th>`. That’s _exactly_ because the rest of the markup is messed up. That’s _exactly_ the reason, why you can’t add a `<tr>` directly to a `<table>` instead of a `<tbody>` or a similar node in a DOM.

Comment: thanks @TrendingNews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**solved your issue please update your jquery with this**

```
var count = $('table.zui-table th.count').length;
console.log(count)
var res = `<th><a>Test</a></th><input type="hidden" name="test-`+(count+1)+`">`; 
$('#view-'+(count)).after(res);
```

**checked your code run well**

Comment: Downvoted because you’ve not taken care of the fundamental mistake of putting things other than `<th>`s or `<td>`s directly in a `<tr>`.

Comment: ok thanks but you can see question first @Xufox...i made change in answer according to question